# Can I handle window scheduler(Window task scheduler) using java program?

Tags: java, windows

I want to execute my Java class through Windows task scheduler.

But I want to register my job programmatically using Java when 
I set time through a Java program in Windows task scheduler. I want to control the start and stop operation of Windows tasks through a Java application.

Is there any way to operate Windows task scheduler 
through Java application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Runtime class to create a task using command line.
[here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785(v=ws.10).aspx) is the link for all the command line parameters to create and modify the task for window task schedular.

Comment: Hi,                                                                                                                 When I write this command then notepad is opened like that I want to open Window Scheduler .                                                                        public static void main(String as[]){
 

 
runComponents("notepad");
 
}
protected static void runComponents(String sComponents)
{
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 try{rt.exec(sComponents);}
 catch(IOException evt){}
}

Comment: Hi ,                                                                                                                      I wrote below command but it is not executing My Java class Test.java.My command is below.Check where am I going wrong? Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  try{rt.exec("schtasks /create /tn \"My App\" /tr D://doha//work//Demo//src//com//Test.java /sc daily /st 10:11 /ed 31/12/2016");
  ;}
  catch(IOException evt){}
 }